# MYSQL if (string in ( 0) ) returns TRUE

Tags: mysql

The following mysql query result returns `'TRUE'`,

```
select if('testString' in ( 0 ), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') from sampleTable
```

Can someone explain why please ?

Comment: It has to do with MySQL's casting rules.  Note that `'testString' IN ('0')`, which is what you should have written, in fact is false.

Comment: What values does `testString` have though?

Comment: @vivek_23 `'testString'` _is_ the value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Then why did OP write `from sampleTable`?

Comment: Because the query is bad, and makes no sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for this correction, indeed the reference to sampleTable was not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using

```
 select  cast('testString' AS UNSIGNED)  from dual ;  // return 0
```

do the fact because the cast for 'testString' AS UNSIGNED is =  0

then

```
select if( 'testString' in ( 0 ), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') from DUAL ;
```

match for casted  value  the 0 in (0) and return TRUE

Comment: Your answer should also ideally mention that comparing strings to integers makes no sense, and in fact on most other databases the OP's query would not even compile.